# How to change user identity when git pushing via ssh?

Tags: node.js, git, github, ssh, amazon-ec2

So I am trying to set up some automated git pushing/pulling on an EC2 instance. Doing this super simply via Node:

```
var add = require('child_process').execSync('git add {FILENAME})
var commit = require('child_process').execSync('git commit -m "{COMMIT_MESSAGE}"')
```

I created a new ssh key on my EC2 instance, adding it as a deploy key on the GitHub repo and allowed write access.

Everything is working perfectly, except the commit author is coming through as `EC2 Default User`. I would like it to be *my own GitHub account*, so that the commits appear on my profile, etc. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commit author has nothing to do with which ssh key is used to authenticate the push.

It has to do with the current Git config:

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

Make sure the values for those local settings are correct (local for the EC2 Git repo), and the next new commits will be with the right author.